# How to format a pandas dataframe and keep original float precision values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, scientific-notation

Im using a pandas dataframe to load a received payload, and when format it  is not formatted as I would like, example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 2.5e-07, 'B': 2.5e-05, 'C': 2.5e-04, 'D': 0.0001, 'E': 0.01}])

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:f}'.format
print(df.to_string())

pd.set_option('display.float_format', str)
print(df.to_string())
```

The output:

```
         A        B        C        D        E
0 0.000000 0.000025 0.000250 0.000100 0.010000

        A       B       C      D    E
0 2.5e-07 2.5e-05 0.00025 0.0001 0.01
```

what I would like to get:

```
        A       B       C      D    E
0 0.0000025 0.000025 0.00025 0.0001 0.01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.format_float_positional`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.float_format', np.format_float_positional)

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'A': 2.5e-07, 'B': 2.5e-05, 'C': 2.5e-04, 'D': 0.0001, 'E': 0.01}
])

print(df.to_string())
```

Or with an [`option_context`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.option_context.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'A': 2.5e-07, 'B': 2.5e-05, 'C': 2.5e-04, 'D': 0.0001, 'E': 0.01}
])

with pd.option_context('display.float_format', np.format_float_positional):
    print(df.to_string())
```

Both Produce:

```
           A        B       C      D    E
0 0.00000025 0.000025 0.00025 0.0001 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the number of floating point decimals but this is applied to all values.

```
In [61]: df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 2.5e-07, 'B': 2.5e-05, 'C': 2.5e-04, 'D': 0.0001, 'E': 0.01}])

In [62]: formats = {"A": "{:,.8f}","B": "{:,.6f}", "C": "{:,.5f}", "D": "{:,.4f}", "E": "{:,.2f}"}

In [63]: for col, f in formats.items():
    ...:     df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: f.format(x))
    ...: 

In [64]: df
Out[64]: 
            A         B        C       D     E
0  0.00000025  0.000025  0.00025  0.0001  0.01
```

Comment: that's problem, I would like to apply the format but without affecting all the fields, in other words maintain the exact precision for each of the fields

Comment: @Leo check the updated answer.

Comment: your answer solves the problem, but the formatting by fields is fixed, in practice, the floating point can have several decimal places

Comment: @Leo yup its hard coded, I would suggest you go with Henry Ecker's answer.